# UrlDecoder decode several times

Tags: java, utf-8, decode, urldecode

Is there any method that fully decodes a String ? For example I have

monta%25C3%25B1a , if I use UrlDecoder.decode method ONCE : it returns  monta%C3%B1a and if I decodify AGAIN , it finally returns montaña (that is the fully decodified string).Is there any method or library in Java that achieves this result?

Comment: No there's nothing like that, because you're not supposed to URLEncode twice. It's up to you to implement something like that, or preferably change the code that performs this double encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
monta[%25]C3[%25]B1a
monta  %  C3  %  B1a    which has a UTF-8 multi-byte sequence
monta       ñ      a
```

It is important to decode with the same Charset as it was encoded.
Evidently it was URL encoded twice, first into UTF-8, and then `%` was still encoded once.

Twice doing the encoding should be repaired, as otherwise an incomprehensible patch remains:

```
s = URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
s = URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: My friend, you are a true genius! Why do they double-encode the url? +1